# The rank of a principal submatrix of a positive semi definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I have this question I met in my studies of matrix theory on which I need help:

> Let A be positive semidefinite and real of order $ n \times n $. Let $ A[\alpha] $ be a principal submatrix of A (the submatrix of A indexed by rows and columns given by the vector $ \alpha $) and we are asked to prove the following equalities of rank 
>   $$\DeclareMathOperator\rk{rank} \rk A[\alpha|1,2,...,n] = \rk A[1,2,...,n|\alpha] = \rk A[\alpha] $$ and we are given the following hint: we are told to assume $ \alpha=\{1,...,k\} $ and as A is positive semidefinite we may factorize it as $ A=BB^T $ where B is the block 2x1 matrix of the form $ B=\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix} $ where X is a $ k \times k $ matrix.

To be honest, I have no real idea how to use the clue and why they ask us to make the assumption about $ \alpha=\{1,2,...,k\} $ and how to proceed to the general equality we are asked to prove. I appreciate all helps.

Comment: I edited the formatting of the maths so that it is more readable. Please check that this still has the intended meaning.

Comment: @zarathustra thank you looks lovely and all correct

Comment: Can you explain what is the matrix $A[\alpha| 1,\dots,n]$?

Comment: @zarathustra yes, it is the submatrix of A whose rows are indexed by $\alpha$  and whose columns are all columns of A

Comment: This first part of the hint is OK. Suppose the size of $\alpha$ is $k$. Up to a permutation, you may assume without loss of generality that $A[\alpha]$ is the **leading** $k\times k$ principal submatrix, i.e. $\alpha=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$. The second part of the hint is definitely wrong, however. Note that $k$ is arbitrary but the rank of $A$ is not. If $k<\operatorname{rank}(A)$, the product $BB^T$ can't possibly be equal to $A$.

Comment: @user1551 : thanks maybe the hint is flawed but do you agree with the equality and could you please help in solving the question without the flawed hint?

Comment: @zbigniew2015 The first equality is trivial because the rank of a matrix is equal to the rank of its transpose. For the second one, suppose $\alpha=\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ and $A[\alpha]=X$, i.e. $A$ is in the form of $\pmatrix{X&Y\\ Y^T&Z}$. Note that $A$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $\pmatrix{QXQ^T&QY\\ Y^TQ^T&Z}$ is positive semidefinite. So you may assume that $X$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: @user1551 : Right, but how would I show equality of rank to one of the other two submatrices stated?

Comment: @zbigniew2015 Well, that's your job. You may try a few examples first. E.g. do you see why $\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}x&0&\ast\\ 0&0&y\\ \hline\ast&y&z\end{array}\right]$ is *never* positive semidefinite when $y$ is nonzero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea: take $B = \pmatrix{X\\Y}$ where $X$ is a $k \times n$ matrix, where $B$ is such that $BB^T = A$.  In particular, we have
$$
A = \pmatrix{XX^T & XY^T\\YX^T & YY^T}
$$

Let $P = \pmatrix{I & 0}$, where $I$ is the $k \times k$ identity matrix.  Notice that for $\alpha = \{1,\dots,k\}$, we have
$$
A[\alpha] = PAP^T = (PB)(PB)^T = XX^T
$$
Conclude that $A[\alpha]$ has the same rank as $PB = X$.  On the other hand, 
$$
A[\alpha \mid 1,\dots,n] = PA = (PB)B^T = XB^T
$$
thus, we conclude that the rank of $A[\alpha \mid 1,\dots,n]$ is at most the rank of $X$, which is to say that 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A[\alpha \mid 1,\dots,n]) \leq 
\operatorname{rank}(A[\alpha])
$$
I think you'll find that the reverse inequality, $\operatorname{rank}(A[\alpha \mid 1,\dots,n]) \geq 
\operatorname{rank}(A[\alpha])$, is a bit more obvious.